# Why do power and power loss have the same formula?

Tags: power, power-electronics

In a practice problem this formula was used: Wcu = Vs×Is + Vp×Ip. Now VI is power, so adding total primary and secondary power is power loss.

Does it mean all the power is lost?

Answer (score 0):

Define what you mean by power "lost". For example, if your definition is simply power that is removed from the circuit, that does not imply wasted or useful power which then depends on context. Useful power and wasted power are still both power after all and math does not make value judgements.

Comment: Actually it's a practice of copper loss and lecturer said that it can be said as power loss due to copper material so I directly asked naming it power loss what I am asking is why it's same as power's formula cause then it means all the power got loss ?

Comment: It doesn't change my answer. If you're using a transformer would you rather have more or less power dissipated by the resistance in the transformer's windings? What if it was a heater rather than a transformer? The math does not make a distinction because power is power.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for power loss in the transformer is \$ (V_p \times I_p) - (V_s \times I_p) \$, or *primary_power - secondary_power*. The loss is due to copper losses (resistive and eddy losses) and core losses. A **perfect** transformer, the input and output power are the same, thus, zero power loss due to the transformer.

Not sure of what that equation is trying to say, but it is in error if describing transformer efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

VI is the  formula for power, regardless of whether it is lost, delivered or consumed.

\$V_sI_s\$ is the power **delivered** by the secondary to the circuitry attached to the secondary. Some of the power is converted to heat by the circuitry. This power is **lost**. Some of the power is **consumed** by the circuitry to do the intended work.

\$V_pI_p\$ is the power **delivered** by the source to the primary. Some of the power is converted to heat by the resistive losses and the magnetizing losses of the core material.

The sum of these quantities has no meaning. The difference between the two is transformer efficiency.

\$V_pI_p\$ is the **total power** delivered by the source to the system.